# Search Results in a UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a search bar that will be searching from an array of names, but the array of names is not listed on the screen. When the user searches, I need the height of my table view to be set based on how many results were returned.

My search functionality works, I just want to have the table view of results only show up if there are results.

I was thinking somewhere in this function I could set the Table View's height but only found something for setting it's rows height.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
        tableView.rowHeight = 50.0
        return results.count
}
```

Comment: Either take reference of table in the class and hide and unhide tableview based on datasource i.e. array count. easiest way and make sure you place tableview on top of all other controls except search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if results.count
       tableView.hidden = false
    else
       tableView.hidden = true

    return results.count
}
```

There may be some typo error, but you can use this logic, i have used many times. on each reload of table, table data source will count whether there are any records in array or not. If records then show tableview, if not then hide. you can add nice animation with alpha from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0. and if you have taken reference of tableview by IBOutlet then use that tableview name overhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a function to set the tableView height.

If you're using AutoLayout you have to set a constraint for height and change this as you need.

If you're not using AutoLayout then you change the tavleview frame to change it's height.

Comment: So it doesn't seem like there is a way to have a search bar results open up in a table view then...?

Comment: You can have the results open up, but you have to manage it yourself. There's nothing built in to do it for you.